# General Triangle Inequality conditions for equality

Tags: inequality, vectors

I am trying to find necessary and sufficient conditions for the triangle equality to be satisfied:

$$|x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n| = |x_1| + |x_2| + \cdots + |x_n|$$

where $x_i$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

I am guessing the condition is analogous to the $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$ case, namely that $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n$ are a linearly dependent set. I can prove this is necessary, but not that it is sufficient, which it may well not be.

Comment: Note that linearly dependent alone does not implies equality even in $|x+y|$ case, the scalar multiple must also be positive.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Hm, I see. why is that?

Comment: Consider $x=1,y=-1$ in $\Bbb R^1$. Clearly they are linearly dependent but     $|x+y|=0\ne 2=|x|+|y|$

Comment: @BigbearZzz Ah yes of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that none of $x_1,x_2,...,x_{n+1}$ is zero, observe that when $n=1$ 
$$|x_1+x_2|=|x_1|+|x_2|
$$
if and only if $\exists c_1>0$ such that $x_2=c_1x_1$.

By triangle inequality $|x_1+...+x_n+x_{n+1}|\le |x_1+...+x_n|+|x_{n+1}|$ so if 
$$|x_1+...+x_n+x_{n+1}|= |x_1|+...+|x_n|+|x_{n+1}|$$
,we'd have $|x_1|+...+|x_n|\le|x_1+...+x_n|$ which implies that 
$$|x_1|+...+|x_n|=|x_1+...+x_n|$$

Proceed inductively, assume that 
$$|x_1+...+x_n|=|x_1|+...+|x_n|
$$
if and only if $\exists c_1,...,c_{n-1}>0$ such that $x_{i+1}=c_ix_1$ whenever $i=1,2,...,n-1$.
If we have
$$|x_1+...+x_n+x_{n+1}|=|x_1|+...+|x_n|+|x_{n+1}|
$$
then 
$$|x_1+...+x_n+x_{n+1}|=|x_1+...+x_n|+|x_{n+1}|
$$
so $\exists c^*_n>0$ such that $x_{n+1}=c^*_n(x_1+...+x_n)=c^*_n(1+c_1+...+c_{n-1})x_1$. By letting $c_n=c^*_n(1+c_1+...+c_{n-1})$, we arrive the conclusion that

> $|x_1+...+x_n+x_{n+1}|=|x_1|+...+|x_n|+|x_{n+1}|$
>
> if and only if $\exists c_1,...,c_n>0$ such that $x_{i+1}=c_ix_1$.

The case where some of $x_i=0$ can be tackled analogously with some caution.

Comment: The proof might look a little bit confusing since I was having a bad time formatting it, please feel free to ask for clarifications. I am actually considering rewriting it :P

Comment: Not so clear what you mean by "we'd have $|x_1|+...+|x_n|\le|x_1+...+x_n|$", isn't that the wrong way round?

Comment: No, since
$$\begin{align}
|x_1|+...+|x_n|+|x_{n+1}| &= |x_1+...+x_n+x_{n+1}| \\
&\le  |x_1+...+x_n|+|x_{n+1}|
\end{align}$$
Together with triangle inequality $|x_1|+...+|x_n|\ge |x_1+...+|x_n| $ yield the equality $|x_1|+...+|x_n|= |x_1+...+|x_n|$.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying

Comment: So basically, $|x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n| = |x_1| + |x_2| + \cdots + |x_n|$ if and only if they all point in the same direction. Quite intuitive if you ask me :)